# Cinema Booking System Class Diagram Design

Tags: class, uml, class-diagram

[image]

Hello all!

I have a question about where should the seats be assigned to keep track if it's booked for a showtime.
There is currently two way i thought of.

1) Assign the seats to the showtime instead of cinema. However this means that for each showtime it may have a different number of seats( which should not be true).
2) Check if the seat is assigned by accessing moviergoer->booking-> movieticket->seat number. 
This method is tedious and uses more processing time. But i feel it's the right way as it will mean that the seats will be fixed.

I'm sorry if any other part of my diagram is wrongly drawn. However please guide me through this main question! I will be glad to get feedback for other part of my diagram too.
I really hope to learn more from this scenario.

Comment: I don't know which tool you used to draw the class diagram, but the notation you use for association is wrong. An Association has an open arrow like `-->` (if it has an arrow at all)

Comment: great ! thx bro! using visual paradigm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your design seems ok so far. Just a few observations:

- you should remove the navigation in general since it does not add much value
- the association from `Booking` to `ShowTime` seems superfluous as the `Ticket` already holds the needed information
- re-think about duplicating `cinema/movie:string` in `ShowTime` as it adds unwanted redundancy
- why do you have a `<<use>>` iso. an association in `Review`?

A seat is related to the cinema and the cinema offers show times.  So 1) is ok.

**Edit**: You would map the ticket like this:

[image]

The both `ID` roles would map the ids in `ShowTime` and `Seat`. I would use an artificial integer for the `seatID` and likely some `HHMM` format for the `showTimeID`.

Comment: hi thomas! thx again! What do you mean by navigation? Also about the showtime seats question, which is the right way?

Comment: the arrows at the end of the associations

Comment: Isn't the seat an composition by the cinema? 
 if option one were  done, each showtime have to be assigned the same number of seats. Shouldn't the number of seats be the same for each cinema?  Sorry for that.

Comment: You already have a composition from seat to cinema. According to my first sentence this confirms it's correct (from my POV). I have been in different cinemas and they all had a different number of seats. Maybe in your area this is different and the have all the same number of seats ;o)

Comment: Yes I understand that. If that's the case my seat were to be assigned to showtime, how do I draw the diagram uml diagram? Because the seats were already an composition to the cinema.

Comment: http://www.vertabelo.com/_file/blog/a-database-model-for-a-movie-theater-reservation-system/Movie-theater.png example the representation of the seat reserved in database is that it will have take both the showtimeid and seatid as an reference, how shall it be modelled in uml

Comment: You can think of the `MovieTicket` as association class having two foreign keys (showTimeID/seatID) in the DB mapping.

Comment: so in terms of uml maping, if i were to include the movieticket with two foregin keys showtimeid and seatid, it will be as an string attribute of those two class? or? 

Is it possible to draw out that part of the UML diagram? sorry